# In elliptic curve cryptography, how is "A dot A" computed?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I was just reading Ars Technica's [primer on ECC](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/10/a-relatively-easy-to-understand-primer-on-elliptic-curve-cryptography/2/). Somewhere near the middle of the second page, the author introduces the "dot" operation that takes an elliptic curve and two other known points, giving a third unique point.

However, the author then claims that A dot A equals B. That is, if the two first points are the same, it's possible to come up with a unique third intersecting point. How is this possible? Intuition tells me that there is an infinite number of possible intersections if the two first points are the same.

Comment: Your geometric intuition is betraying you here, I think. Thinking of elliptic curve groups as lying in the Cartesian plane from high-school algebra is useful shorthand but can lead you astray if you take it too literally. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) might help you understand elliptic curves algebraically.

Comment: To use the geometrical interpretation, for $A\cdot A$ we take the line tangential to the curve at $A$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that a line through a single point can intersect the curve in many other points. But you don't choose just any line. You choose the tangent through $A$. And that line will intersect the curve in exactly one point (which usually isn't, but may actually be $A$).

It is an interesting and useful exercise to actually do these computations with the formulae. Choose an elliptic curve, choose a point (not with $y$-coordinate $0$), find the curve's tangent line, then compute the remaining intersection point. (This is easy. You have two equations $Y^2 = X^3 + aX + B$ and $Y=\alpha X + \beta$. Eliminating $Y$, you get a cubic equation in $X$ and you know a double zero, namely the $x$-coordinate of the point you are trying to double.)